# I imported a jQuery plugin into my project and my <a> tag CSS is overriding its <a> tag CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have a page that uses certain styles that I have defined.

On the same page I just imported an external jQuery plugin that uses its own styles, including, for example, an `<a>` tag style that is being overridden by my own.

**How do I ensure that the styles in my stylesheet do not override the styles in the stylesheet of the jQuery plugin?**

Comment: What plugin is this?  It's pretty uncool to be re-styling generic tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** My jQuery adds a stylesheet AFTER MY stylesheet

> Use **!important** inside *your* stylesheet to override any other styles.

```
a {
    border: none !important; /* listen to me god dammit! */
}
```

**2)** My jQuery adds a `style` attribute to my element which is **overriding** my styles.

> Use the `style` **attribute selector** inside your stylesheet

```
a[style] {
    border: none !important; /* I even override inline styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if they both apply to just the a element, then CSS will use whichever one it finds last. include your stylesheet after the plug in to make sure it is the one that gets used.